# How can I check system usage when using google cloudml?

Tags: google-cloud-ml

I ran a cloudml job with BASIG_GPU.

I would like to check Walker's cpu, gpu, and momory usage, but is it possible?

The reason for this is that I applied for one GPU, but I want to see the change in gpu usage when I turn two jobs (scaleTier: BASIG_GPU).

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The CPU and memory utilization charts are available on the ML Engine job page on your Google Cloud Console, and the GPU utilization metrics are under development.

Comment: When I click on the job name, I can not find any chart other than the detail view.This means [there](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/monitor-training) are no 4 in *Monitoring Resource Consumption*. Why?

Comment: There should be charts on the page. If not, please send us your project number an job id via cloudml-feedback@google.com and we will check if it's a bug. Thanks!

Comment: Update: the charts were shown up when the language was English but disappeared after switching the language to Korean. We are investigating the issue.